# Что в C/C++ считается сигнатурой функции?

Tags: c++

Возьмём такой пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
int Foo (int x);
int main()
{
    std::cout<< Foo (10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
int Foo (const int x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Он успешно скомпилируется. Получается, компилятор проигнорировал, что в прототипе `const` отсутствует, а в реализации он есть. Что же в таком случае компилятор считает сигнатурой? Какие пункты стандарта регулируют этот вопрос?

Comment: насчет стандарта не скажу, но вот описание на `cpp ref`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#:~:text=Even%20though%20top%2Dlevel%20cv%2Dqualifiers%20on%20the%20parameters%20are%20discarded%20in%20function%20declarations%2C%20they%20modify%20the%20type%20of%20the%20parameter%20as%20visible%20in%20the%20body%20of%20a%20function%3A

Comment: Вот стандарт: http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.signature#def:signature (кто-то мне еще говорил, что для шаблонных функций возвращаемый тип тоже входит в сигнатуру, но стандарт ничего такого не говорит).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, посмотрите ниже, там есть для шаблона функции определение.

Comment: @isnullxbh Блин, точно! Тыкнул на первую ссылку из предметного указателя, и не посмотрел, что их там много.

Comment: тип `int` и`int const/volatile` - один. тип `int * ` и`int * const/volatile` - один. типы `int *` и `int const/volatile *` - разные. Сигнатура функции подразумевает только тип без `const/volatile`.

Answer (score -2):

Параметры функций, указанные как const, не могут меняться внутри функции.
При объявлении функции, в ее прототипе для параметров, которые передаются по значению, указывать const необязательно, т.е. записи идентичные:

```
int Foo (int x); 
int Foo (const int x);
```

Т.е. для параметров, передаваемых по значению, const всего лишь защитит на этапе компиляции этот параметр от изменения внутри функции
Если изменить вашу `Foo` таким образом:

```
int Foo (const int x)
{
    x++;
    return x*x;
}
```

Получите ошибку компиляции

> error: increment of read-only parameter ‘x’

Comment: Ответ не по теме. Вопрос не в том, что означает `const`, а в том, что считается за сигнатуру функции.

Comment: еще раз повторяю. сигнатура вашей функции int Foo(int), а const для параметров, передаваемых по значению с точки зрения компилятора - мишура! Проведите эксперимент - скомпилируйте в библиотеку с разными вариантами - (int), (const int),(int*),(const int*) и изучите экспортируемые символы без (хоть с деманглом хоть без)